# How to Check discord member roles

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm have a problem with a part of my python code , I created a discord bot for showing the balances of a game to users they are 3 type of people I mean 3 different discord role
when i use !payment i want check their role and show their balances (right now there is alot of records i want to make it clean)

````py
elif message.content.startswith('!payment'):
        await message.add_reaction("✅")
        if not any(role.name in['Guild Master','Calculator','Programmer'] for role in message.author.roles):
            await message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use this command")
            return
        c.execute('SELECT Tag,Balance,Date_Time FROM dbr1')
        data=c.fetchall()
        async def send_embeds(message,data):
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Information", description="**Details for all users.**", colour=discord.Colour(int(custom_color, 16)))
            field_count = 0
            for keys in data:
                tag, balance, date_time = keys
                f_p_c = '{:,.0f}'.format(balance).replace(',', '.')
                embed.add_field(name=f':pencil:___________________________', value=f":id:{tag}\n ``` Balance : {f_p_c}\n ```", inline=False)
                field_count += 1
                if field_count >= 25:
                    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="Information", description="details for all users.", colour=discord.Colour(int(custom_color, 16)))
                    field_count=0
            if field_count>0:
                    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        await send_embeds(message, data)
        process_payment=False
````

I cant put their roles in my database i want program extract their roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing formatting and correcting some syntax (based on the answer by @hossein-dahaei), you can see the corrected code. It uses the multiple embeds functionality present within Discord to bundle multiple embeds together in a single message.

```
if message.content.startswith('!payment'):
    await message.add_reaction("✅")
    allowed_roles = ['Guild Master', 'Calculator', 'Programmer']
    user_roles = [role.name for role in message.author.roles]

    if not any(role in allowed_roles for role in user_roles):
        await message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use this command")
        return

    c.execute('SELECT Tag, Balance, Date_Time FROM dbr1')
    data = c.fetchall()

    embeds = []

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Information", 
        description="Details for all users.", 
        colour=discord.Colour(int(custom_color, 16))
    )

    embeds.append(embed)

    field_count = 0

    for keys in data:
        tag, balance, date_time = keys
        formatted_balance = '{:,.0f}'.format(balance).replace(',', '.')

        embed.add_field(
            name=f':pencil:___________________________',
            value=f":id:{tag}\n Balance : {formatted_balance}\n",
            inline=False
        )

        field_count += 1

        if field_count >= 25:
            embeds.append(embed)
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Information", 
                description="details for all users.", 
                colour=discord.Colour(int(custom_color, 16))
            )
            field_count = 0

        if len(embeds) >= 10:
            await message.channel.send(embeds=embeds)
            embeds = []
            field_count = 0

    # If we didn't reach 10 embeds, and the 
    # other send branch is not run, send the rest of the embeds
    if len(embeds) > 0:
        await message.channel.send(embeds=embeds)

process_payment = False
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the roles of the Discord users and include them in your database, you can modify your code as follows:

```
elif message.content.startswith('!payment'):
await message.add_reaction("✅")
allowed_roles = ['Guild Master', 'Calculator', 'Programmer']
user_roles = [role.name for role in message.author.roles]

if not any(role in allowed_roles for role in user_roles):
    await message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use this command")
    return

c.execute('SELECT Tag, Balance, Date_Time FROM dbr1')
data = c.fetchall()

async def send_embeds(message, data):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Information", description="Details for all users.", colour=discord.Colour(int(custom_color, 16)))
    field_count = 0

    for keys in data:
        tag, balance, date_time = keys
        f_p_c = '{:,.0f}'.format(balance).replace(',', '.')
        embed.add_field(name=f':pencil:___________________________', value=f":id:{tag}\n Balance : {f_p_c}\n", inline=False)
        field_count += 1

        if field_count >= 25:
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Information", description="details for all users.", colour=discord.Colour(int(custom_color, 16)))
            field_count = 0

    if field_count > 0:
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

await send_embeds(message, data)

process_payment = False
```

Comment: great answer! just out of curiosity, did you get this from chatgpt?